AndroidTest Compose IllegalStateException: Given component holder class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt
I've seen a few things now where you are trying to inject a viewModel using hilt navigation and it is giving errors. I'm using Hilt Navigation with Compose and I'm having problems with doing UI tests.
This question is the most similar.
I have an abstract viewModel which is being inherited by 5 different viewmodels and the viewModel is scoped to the backstack.  Everything works fine on the emulator and an real device, just not in UI tests.
Here is the abstract viewModel:
abstract class ProposeNewGoalViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val proposedGoalUiDataInit = ProposedGoalUiData(
        targetAmount = null,
        startYear = LocalDateTime.now().year.toString(),
        singleOrRecurring = SingleOrRecurring.SINGLE,
        goalName = null,
        wantWishOrNeed = WantWishOrNeed.NEED,
        yearCareProvidedStart = LocalDateTime.now().year.toString()
    )

     open fun resetState() { 
        ......
     }

//methods
.......

}

Here is one of the viewModels:
@HiltViewModel
class Category1OneTimeOrRecurringViewModel @Inject constructor() : ProposeNewGoalViewModel() {

    override fun resetState() {
        super.resetState()
        showRecurrenceFormFields.update { false }
        onTargetAmountChanged("")
        onStartYearChanged("")
        onFrequencyChanged("")
        onNumberOfOccurrencesChanged("")
    }
}

So nothing earth shattering.  Here's where I get the error in my androidTest:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class GoalsFragment() { 

@AndroidEntryPoint
class GoalsFragment : BaseFragment() {

.......

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return ComposeView(requireActivity()).apply {
        setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
        setContent {
            GoalsNav(
                goalsViewModel = goalsViewModel,
                proposeNewGoalViewModel = proposeNewGoalScreenViewModel,
                popBackStack = { activity?.finish() },
                navigateToAccounts = {
                    landingViewModel.performNavigationSubject.onNext(R.id.accounts)
                },
                navigateToMyTeamMessage = { messageType ->
                    findNavController().navigateSafe(
                        R.id.action_goalsLanding_to_myTeamNewMessage,
                        MyTeamNewMessageFragmentArgs(
                            messageType
                        ).toBundle()
                    )
                },
                fragmentNavController = findNavController()
            )
        }
    }
}
}

@SuppressLint("NavigateSafe")
@Composable
fun GoalsNav(
    goalsViewModel: GoalsViewModel,
    proposeNewGoalViewModel: ProposeNewGoalScreenViewModel,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    popBackStack: () -> Unit,
    navigateToAccounts: () -> Unit,
    navigateToMyTeamMessage: (MyTeamMessageType) -> Unit,
    fragmentNavController: NavController
) {
    EJTheme {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = GOALS_ROUTE
        ) {

        ////////////////////THIS WORKS FINE IN TEST    
        composable(route = PROPOSE_NEW_GOAL_ROUTE) { backStackEntry ->
            ProposeNewGoalScreen(
                viewModel = hiltViewModel<ProposeNewGoalScreenViewModel>(backStackEntry),
                navigateBack = { navController.popBackStack() },
                onNavigateToGoalType = {
                    navController.navigate(
                        "$FILL_OUT_PROPOSED_NEW_GOAL_ROUTE/${it.goalType}"
                    )
                },
            )}
        
        /////////////////ILLEGAL STATE
        composable(route = "$FILL_OUT_PROPOSED_NEW_GOAL_ROUTE/{$PROPOSE_GOAL_TYPE_ARG}") { backStackEntry ->

            val goalTypeArg =
                backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(PROPOSE_GOAL_TYPE_ARG)?.toInt()
            val selectedGoalTypeEnum = goalTypeArg?.let { GoalType.getGoal(it) }
            val proposeNewGoal = selectedGoalTypeEnum?.let { ProposeNewGoal.getGoalBasedOnGoalType(it) }
            val proposeNewGoalViewModelForForm = when (proposeNewGoal?.category) {
                Category.CATEGORY_1_SINGLE_OR_REOCCURRING -> {
                    hiltViewModel(backStackEntry) as Category1OneTimeOrRecurringViewModel. ///////error happens here
                }
                Category.CATEGORY_2_EDUCATION ->  {
                    hiltViewModel(backStackEntry) as Category2EducationViewModel
                }
                Category.CATEGORY_3_SINGLE_OCCURRENCE -> {
                    hiltViewModel(backStackEntry) as Category3SingleTimeViewModel
                }
                Category.CATEGORY_4_PROVIDE_CARE -> {
                    hiltViewModel(backStackEntry) as Category4ProvideCareViewModel
                }
                Category.CATEGORY_5_BEQUEST -> {
                    hiltViewModel(backStackEntry) as Category5LeaveBequestViewModel
                }
                null -> hiltViewModel(backStackEntry) as Category1OneTimeOrRecurringViewModel
            }
            ProposeNewGoalForm(
                viewModel = proposeNewGoalViewModelForForm,
                navigateBack = { navController.navigate(PROPOSE_NEW_GOAL_ROUTE) { popUpTo(PROPOSE_NEW_GOAL_ROUTE) { inclusive = true } } },
                onNavigateBackToGoals = navigateToGoals,
                validateForm = {
                    proposeNewGoalViewModelForForm.validateForm()
                },
                selectedGoalType = goalTypeArg,
                onNavigateToConfirmation = { navController.navigate("$FILL_OUT_PROPOSED_NEW_GOAL_ROUTE_CONFIRMATION/$goalTypeArg") },
            )
        }
}
}

I tried making the abstract class an open class with HiltViewModel and no dice.  I think it's a bug.
Test SetUp
@HiltAndroidTest
class ProposeNewGoalNavigationTests {

    lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    private val context: Context
        get() = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()

    private val goalsRepository: GoalsRepo = mock()
    private val featureTogglesRepo: FeatureTogglesRepo = mock()
    private val userDataRepo: UserDataRepo = mock()
    private val staticContentRepo: StaticContentRepository = mock()
    private val analyticRepository: AnalyticsRepo = mock()
    private val documentsRepo: DocumentsRepo = mock()
    private val messagesRepository: MyTeamMessagesRepository = mock()

    private val documentUseCase = DocumentDownloadUseCase(
        documentsRepo,
        mock(),
        "EJFileAbsolutePath"
    )
    private val launchDarklyFlagsRepo: LaunchDarklyFlagsRepo = mock()

    @get:Rule
    val setupRepoRule = SetupRepoRule()

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Mock
    val dispatcherProvider: DispatcherProvider = Mockito.mock()

    val goalsRepo: GoalsRepo = mock()

    @BindValue
    val proposeNewGoalScreenViewModel = ProposeNewGoalScreenViewModel()

   @BindValue
   val confirmVM = ConfirmNewProposedGoalViewModel(
    goalsRepository = goalsRepository,
    userDataRepo = userDataRepo,
    featureTogglesRepo = featureTogglesRepo,
    messagesRepository = messagesRepository,
    dispatcherProvider = dispatcherProvider
    )

    @BindValue
    val category1FormVM = Category1OneTimeOrRecurringViewModel()

    @BindValue
    val category2FormVM = Category2EducationViewModel()

    @BindValue
    val category3FormVM = Category3SingleTimeViewModel()

    @BindValue
    val category4FormVM = Category4ProvideCareViewModel()

    @BindValue
    val category5FormVM = Category5LeaveBequestViewModel()

    @Before
    fun setupNavHost() {
        hiltRule.inject()
         
   

    val goalViewModel = GoalsViewModel(
        goalsRepository = goalsRepository,
        featureTogglesRepo = featureTogglesRepo,
        userDataRepo = userDataRepo,
        savedStateHandle = SavedStateHandle(mapOf(GoalsViewModel.ON_TRACK_CALCULATED to false)),
        dispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
        analyticsRepository = analyticRepository,
        staticContentRepo = staticContentRepo,
        documentDownloadUseCase = documentUseCase,
        launchDarklyFlagsRepo = launchDarklyFlagsRepo
        )

        composeTestRule.setContent {
            navController = 
    TestNavHostController(LocalContext.current)
        
 navController.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(DialogNavigator())      
 
navController.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(ComposeNavigator())
            GoalsNav(
                goalsViewModel = goalViewModel,
                proposeNewGoalViewModel = 
 proposeNewGoalScreenViewModel,
                navController = navController,
                popBackStack = {},
                navigateToAccounts = {},
                navigateToMyTeamMessage = {},
                fragmentNavController = rememberNavController()
            )
        }
    }
}


If your activity an @AndroidEntryPoint? That appears to be what the error message is complaining about.

Yes, it all works outside of ui tests.  I wish it were that simple

Your error message says you are using androidx.activity.ComponentActivity, which is not your custom activity. Please include your test set up.

@ianhanniballake Added the test set up.

For those are that looking for the answer:
Compose tests use ComponentActivity to set content and this is not annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint which is required by Hilt.  I solved this issue by adding a HiltComponentActivity to debug and adding it to the debug manifest:
HiltComponentActivity:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HiltComponentActitivity: ComponentActivity()

Then in my test:
@get:Rule val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<HiltComponentActivity>()

Referenced here:  https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3394

I also had to add this activity to manifest file then worked
